# killing Form is null for some elements of Lie algebra of symplectic group

Tags: linear-algebra, lie-groups, lie-algebras, symplectic-linear-algebra

Let $\mathfrak{g} = \{X ∈ gl_{2n} (\Bbb R), ^tXJ + JX = 0\}$ where $J=\begin{pmatrix}
0 & I_n \\
-I_n & 0
\end{pmatrix}$

Let $i ∈ [1, ...,n]$ and $H_i = E_{i,i} − E_{n+i,n+i} (i = 1, ..., n)$.

Prove that $\exists f\in Aut(\mathfrak{g})$ such that $f (H_i ) = −H_i$ and $f (H_j ) = H_j$ for  $i ∈ [1, ...,n]\setminus \{i\}$

Prove that $B(H_i , H_j ) = 0$

What I did:

I found that $\{E_{k,l, k\ne l}, H_{i,i\in \{1,...,n\}}\}$ is a basis for $\mathfrak{g}$. so an example of such $f\in Aut(\mathfrak{g})$ could be:

$f: H_i\to -H_i$

$H_j\to H_j$ $(j\ne i)$

$E_{k,l, k\ne l} \to E_{k,l, k\ne l}$

This is an automorphism as it sends a basis of $\mathfrak{g}$ to a basis of $\mathfrak{g}$.

Now concerning $B(H_i , H_j ) = 0$, I have no clue on how to proceed.

Could you please give me help or hints? Thank you.

Comment: It is certainly meant that $f$ is an automorphism *of Lie algebras*, so it's not sufficient to just check it sends a basis to a basis (this shows it's an automorphism of vector spaces). You also have to check that $f([x,y]) = [f(x), f(y)]$ for all $x,y \in \mathfrak{g}$ (although by (bi)linearity it would suffice to check than on basis elements).

Comment: Right @TorstenSchoeneberg I should check that too! thank you!

Comment: Also, I'm not even convinced that what you write down is really a basis. If it were, the dimension of the whole thing would be $4n^2-n$; but it actually is $2n^2+2n$, which is strictly smaller for $n \ge 2$. I guess that e.g. for $n=2$ the matrices $E_{1,4}$ and $E_{2,3}$ are actually not contained in $\mathfrak{g}$, but one of $E_{1,4} \pm E_{2,3}$ is. The messiness of these computations suggests that there must be a smarter way to do this. How much structure theory of Lie algebras are you allowed to use? Do you have the root system theory available at all?

Comment: Right @TorstenSchoeneberg! I messed up with the basis. What is sure is that $H_{i,i\in \{1,...,n\}}$ is a basis of the subalgebra of diagonal matrices of $\mathfrak{g}$ and that $\{E_{k,l, k\ne l}, H_{i,i\in \{1,...,n\}}\}$ is generating $\mathfrak{g}$. Unfortunately I checked on Wikipedia what is a root system and I have 0-knowledge about it. However concerning dimension of $\mathfrak{g}$ I found $2n^2+n$ as the bloc from of an element of   $\mathfrak{g}$ is $J=\begin{pmatrix}
A & B \\
C & -^tA
\end{pmatrix}$ with B and C symetric matrices

Comment: The $H_{i,i}$ are certainly ok, but as I said: No, some of the $E_{k,l}$ are *not even contained* in $\mathfrak{g}$ (and so they don't generate it)! Your own block form in the last comment shows that by saying that $B, C$ have to be symmetric. E.g. for $n=2$, the matrix $E_{1,4} = \pmatrix{0&0&0&1\\0&0&0&0\\0&0&0&0\\0&0&0&0}$ is *not* of this form. (But $E_{1,4}+E_{2,3}$ is.)